# scipy.misc.imshow RuntimeError('Could not execute image view')

Tags: python, image, scipy, centos7, imshow

I am testing [scipy.misc.imshow](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imshow.html) and I got **RuntimeError: Could not execute image viewer**.

I am using Python3.4 and running it on CentOS 7.

```
import scipy.misc
img = scipy.misc.imread('Data/cat.jpg')
assert len(img.shape) == 3
img_resized = scipy.misc.imresize(img, (224, 224))
img_answer = (img_resized/255.0).astype('float32')
scipy.misc.imshow(img_answer)
```

And I got an error:

```
sh: see: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py", line 71, in <module>
    globals = run_file(file, None, None)
  File "/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py", line 31, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myVQA/testgood.py", line 6, in <module>
    scipy.misc.imshow(img_answer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py", line 442, in imshow
    raise RuntimeError('Could not execute image viewer.')
RuntimeError: Could not execute image viewer.
```

It says that the `see` command is not found. Where is the `see` command installed on CentOS7? How can I fix the problem?

I tried to add `SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER=/bin/eog` to `/etc/profile`
but it seems to be no help.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [matplotlib.pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) as an alternative to using [SciPy's imshow](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imshow.html) method.

```
import scipy.misc
img = scipy.misc.imread('Data/cat.jpg')
assert len(img.shape) == 3
img_resized = scipy.misc.imresize(img, (224, 224))
img_answer = (img_resized/255.0).astype('float32')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(np.uint8(img_tinted))
plt.show()
```

[image: Original Image] => [image: Output Image]

P.S. If we directly plot the image as `plt.imshow(img_tinted)`, then it might sometimes give weird results if the data presented to it is not in the form of unit8. Hence, to prevent this we explicitly cast `np.uint8` to the image such as `plt.imshow(np.uint8(img_tinted))`

The following images show output in the absence of np.uint8

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works. But then, it doesn't solve the problem of scipy's `imshow()`, which the question is about.

Comment: Suggesting another package does not solve the problem but ignores it. And you do this **after** a simple and real solution to the problem! (I should downvote you but I don't use to do that.)

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by:

1 adding the following to /etc/profile

```
SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER=/bin/eog
export SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER
```

2 reboot

if you do not export SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER,

```
cmd = os.environ.get('SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER', 'see')
```

will not recognize SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER

Answer (score 0):

The following also works for me (much lighter and faster than using matplotlib):

```
from os import environ
environ['SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER'] = {your image viewer pgm} # e.g. C:/IrfanView/i_view32.exe
```

I can then use scipy's imshow().