# scipy.imshow (RuntimeError: Could not execute image viewer)

Tags: python, image, scipy, imshow

I installed scipy with anaconda2. When I test scipy.imshow, I got **RuntimeError: Could not execute image viewer**

```
import scipy.misc as mi
img = mi.imread('F:\Jupyter\opencv\quokka.jpg')
mi.imshow(img)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-4-9b0818c43d12>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('F:/Jupyter/opencv/show.py', wdir='F:/Jupyter/opencv')

File "C:\Users\l\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\l\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "F:/Jupyter/opencv/show.py", line 10, in <module>
mi.imshow(img)

File "C:\Users\l\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\pilutil.py", line 443, in imshow
raise RuntimeError('Could not execute image viewer.')

RuntimeError: Could not execute image viewer.
```

[scipy.misc.imshow RuntimeError('Could not execute image view')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229630/scipy-misc-imshow-runtimeerrorcould-not-execute-image-view) has the similar question. It suggested to add SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER. However, I don't know how to do this in windows7. 
Can anyone shed some light on this question?

Comment: This looks like a broken setup as there should be a working default with anaconda. If you got some viewer ready, you can use os.environment to set this variable within python.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Have you tried the solution of the post you mention that is about using matplotlib? This should have been installed with anaconda and you can add the lines `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, `plt.imshow(img)` and `plt.show()` to your program (and remove the `mi.imshow` line).

Comment: Actually, I am working on a image augmentation program and the program has the code about scipy.imshow. The imshow code is work fine with matplotlib and PIL libraries. I just want to figure out what's wrong with scipy.imshow. @ Pierre de Buyl

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER` environment variable to point to the program/executable that can be used to view images on your system. See the docstring of `scipy.misc.imshow` for details.

To be honest, this feature is quite old, not well supported or documented, and should probably be deprecated in the scipy codebase. If you want to view images, I'd recommend using matplotlib and `plt.imshow` instead; it's far better supported in the modern scientific Python stack.

Comment: So how about mac? what the name for the `Preview` in Mac?

Comment: On a Mac I would suggest the same thing: avoid scipy.imshow and instead use plt.imshow, and then the question of what Preview is called becomes moot.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
from os import environ
environ['SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER'] = {your image viewer pgm} # e.g. C:/IrfanView/i_view32.exe
```

I can then use scipy's imshow().